# How to remap tangent vector for remapped UV coordinates?

Tags: normal-map, vector

I've been using highly scaled detail normal maps through Cycles nodes and eventually realized I had a problem with my tangents.  This creates sometimes subtle artifacts, most obviously when using mapping nodes to rotate my UV coordinates, but also when using mapping nodes to scale my UV coordinates.  I'm scaling by factors of 50 or more so rescaling my UV mapping itself is out of the question even if it wasn't undesirable for other reasons-- Blender just won't let me use coordinates that far out of bounds.

It looks like I can remap the tangent vector using a mapping node, but I don't know how I should do this.  There are a lot of potential things to try and since the artifacts are easily missed, I don't want to rely on trial and error.

Let's say I run my UV coordinates through a 90 degree rotation in Z in texture mode in a cycles mapping node.  How should I transform my tangent vector?  What about if I do a 0.002, 0.010 X,Y scale in texture mode in a cycles mapping node?